# Django rest swagger api list contain its own url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My urls.py shows below:

```
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^v1/', include('apps.api.urls')),
            url(r'^docs/$', schema_view)
        ]
```

[image]

I don't know why it shows docs, can i remove it and how

Comment: It is showing because it may be used for getting `openapi` specification with `application/openapi+json` content-type in header. Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: @Sardorbek Imomaliev, it isn't my api in fact.